# OpenGraph tag is extraneous?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

Working on adding open graph tags to the individual pages of our wedding photography site for use by the Facebook Like button.  I'm close, but I still get one warning
Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:sitename.

```
    <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# website: http://ogp.me/ns/website#">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">
    <meta name="generator" content="jAlbum 9, http://jalbum.net">
    <meta property="fb:admins"               content='1591068265'> 
    <meta property="og:type"                 content="website"> 
    <meta property="og:sitename"             content="Dawn Kelly Photography"> 
    <meta property="og:url"                  content="http://www.DawnKellyPhotography.com/edgarvaht/galleries/FBalbum/fbindex.php?show=slides/NodownLoad.html"> 
    <meta property="og:image"                content="http://www.DawnKellyPhotography.com/edgarvaht/galleries/FBalbum/slides/NodownLoad.jpg">
    <meta property="og:title"                content="Facebook Test Gallery - NodownLoad.jpg">
    <meta property="og:description"          content="Facebook Test Gallery, image: NodownLoad.jpg">
```

Since it is saying it is extraneous, does that mean I don't need the sitename tag?  As for the type, is "website" a good choice, or should I pick "product" or something else since the page is a page to purchase the image.

Comment: Object debugger returns this:

fb:admins: Array of length 1
⍾ 1591068265
og:url: http://www.DawnKellyPhotography.com/edgarvaht/galleries/FBalbum/fbindex.php?show=slides%2FNodownLoad.html
og:type: website
og:title: Facebook Test Gallery - NodownLoad.jpg
og:image: 
og:description: Facebook Test Gallery, image: NodownLoad.jpg
og:updated_time: 1329456586

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A page like that should definitely not use the `website` type as that's intended for whole sites and not individual pages on a site, [`product`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/#types) is probably a more appropriate type. Additionally, the correct property is `og:site_name` and not `og:sitename` so that is probably what is causing your issue.

Comment: DOH!!!  Thanks for catching my glaring oversight.  Apparently, OpenGraph is more exacting than horseshoes and hand grenades.